# Disable MongoDB from rails 3.0.9 application start up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

My project uses both MySQL(for ActiveAdmin tables) and MongoDB(for rake task that does logs file parsing) as database. I have used Mongoid to connect my app to MongoDB. So I just have mongoid.yml file extra in /config directory along with other usual files(No other files to setup MongoDB connection). However whenever I try to run migrations for MySQL or start my app it requires MongoDB running in the background else the server/task wont start and gives an error

`Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)`

Keeping MongoDB continuously running is not required. Please guide me in excluding this compulsion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some discussion on this topic here: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1166

Perhaps you could wrap the connection so that it checks for a certain flag or environment variable which you would use for mysql only mode.